# HTML/CSS: Allow For Background Image Hover and Absolute Positioned Text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

- Have a grayscaled image
- Have text and a button positioned over the grayscaled image
- Allow for a hover-effect on the grayscaled image so that it's colored on hover

The issue I'm running into is that when I'm hovering over the text/button of the absolute-positioned div on top of the image, the hover effect no longer works.

Here's an example:

[image]

Here's my HTML & CSS:

```
<div id="homepage-solutions">
  <div class="image-box">
    <img src="https://azbigmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/metalworking.jpg">
    <div class="text-box">
      <h3>Metalworking</h3>
      <a href="comingsoon" class="btn">Learn More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

#homepage-solutions .image-box {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 250px;
    min-height: 250px;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#homepage-solutions .image-box img {
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    filter: gray;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    filter: grayscale(1);
}
#homepage-solutions .image-box img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
    filter: none;
}
#homepage-solutions .text-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 500px;
}
#homepage-solutions h3 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
#homepage-solutions .text-box p {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
#homepage-solutions .text-box a.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    color: #fff;
    background: #fd5f11;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 6px 20px;
    margin: 5px 0 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}
#homepage-solutions .text-box a.btn:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

Fiddle Links:
https://jsfiddle.net/mwilk/96p7nkw1/5/ https://jsfiddle.net/mwilk/96p7nkw1/6/#&togetherjs=H2kAkloCwG

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Hi***,

Just Edit Selector:

```
#homepage-solutions .image-box img:hover
```

To

```
#homepage-solutions .image-box:hover img
```

See It working

```css
#homepage-solutions .image-box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 250px;
  min-height: 250px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#homepage-solutions .image-box img {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  filter: gray;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
#homepage-solutions .image-box:hover img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
  filter: none;
}
#homepage-solutions .text-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 500px;
}
#homepage-solutions h3 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
#homepage-solutions .text-box p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
#homepage-solutions .text-box a.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  color: #fff;
  background: #fd5f11;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
#homepage-solutions .text-box a.btn:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

```html
    <div id="homepage-solutions">
      <div class="image-box">
        <img
          src="https://azbigmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/metalworking.jpg"
        />
        <div class="text-box">
          <h3>Metalworking</h3>
          <a href="comingsoon" class="btn">Learn More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: OH MY.... Yup, that would do it alright. Wow. Thank you!